# uploading photo to facebook page using wcf service c#

Tags: c#, facebook, wcf

i am uploading photo to facebook page using a wcf service in c#, the exception encountered is

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."}
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(String address, String method, String fileName)



  WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadFile("https://graph.facebook.com/" + albumID + "/photos?access_token=" + accessToken + "&message=" + name, "POST", path);
var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very generic Exception, and you can't say exactly what's going wrong.

Use this exception, You'll get more info.

```
catch (WebException e)
{
   //Read exception here
}
```

Comment: I faced same error once(with some-other task )& this exception helped me to analyze the area of error